# How to program ABB HMI CP6615

Tags: project, plc

I want to program my ABB HMI ABB6615 using software ABB PANEL BUILDER 600. But unfortunately, when I create a project then I didn't get the option for CP6615? What should I do? Attached screenshot shows of HMI models which my software is displaying

TIA

[image]

Comment: The model is CP6615

Comment: Which version number of Panel Builder 600 are you using?

Comment: Panel builder 600 v1.9

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with ABB HMIs, but my guess is that you need to update to a newer version of the programming software to be able to program the CP6615.

I found an [ABB document showing HMI models and compatible software versions](https://search.abb.com/library/Download.aspx?DocumentID=3ADR010309&LanguageCode=en&DocumentPartId=&Action=Launch) that seems to agree with this.  From that document, for the CP6615 it lists versions of PB610 (Panel Builder 600) between V2.6.1.126 and V2.8.1.447.  Your software version of 1.9 is probably too old to support this model.